# how to make slick2D showing movement of my sprite

Tags: java, slick2d

i need some help in Java Slick2D library, from my experience in coding with this library i understood that the class which extends BasicGameState will call the update() and the render() methodes in an infinite loop, my problem is to find a way to call some methodes in render() methode which has some movement of a sprite, for exemple i have this methode :

```
public void move(Graphics g, Image sprite, int X, int Y){
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        g.drawImage(sprite, X+i, Y);
}
```

when i call move(g, sprite, posX, PosY) in render() methode my sprite will teleport to the next 32 pixels without showing animations.
what should i do to solve this problem and make my sprite moving correctly ?

Comment: First it is probably better to calculate movement based on time. As you are talking 2D I suspect you should have a tile set that represents each part of your animation and after a time period you should display the next tile. as for calling your method from the update method there should be a structure that your animation gets attached to. Sorry to be vague but I don't use Slick2D. Old but good book here http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ look at chapter two and see if you can reconcile with the lib you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies in a little bit of what onesixtyfourth had to say.

You need to rely on update intervals. In slick, a common error people tend to make is putting logic code in their render method. This goes against a lot of game making rules, as the render method needs to be as light weight as possible to ensure a good framerate. With that being said, having your move() method in the slick render() method is a bit inefficient/unoptimized. So having logical operations being done on the coordinates of an image in the render() method can be seen as a heavy operation, especially if you are doing this for ALL your moving objects (imagine how hard-hitting a physics engine would be, running in the render method).

To explain what you're seeing (the instant "teleport" to the next 32 pixels), you can simply follow how your code operates. Lets go through:

1. update() method called, checks for input (I'm guessing, as I don't know all your code)

   - finds the player has pressed a move button
2. render() method called

   - wipe screen (double buffer stuff)
   - move was pressed, so call move(); image current position = (x, y)
   - go through loop applying i to x coordinate

     - g.drawImage at all i+x locations
   - print all to screen
3. update() called, no input found
4. render() called

   - wipe screen(double buffer)
   - draw sprite at it's x and y
   - does not loop through move() because no input was pressed

Note that, when you looped through the move() method, you told the graphics object to draw that KIND of image (not treating the image as it's own object, i.e. one instance) several times over that x+i coorindates. This happened in ONE frame. So, by the next frame, you wouldn't have noticed any of the images were ever drawn, because it happened too quickly as the double buffer "cleans" the screen (notice when the "wipe screen" happens).

THE FIX:

To fix this problem, if you have an entity class (some kind of "player class" that has it's own image), you can set it up like this:

```
update() {
    if(input is a direction of movement) {
        player.direction = direction of move
    } else { player.direction = player.IDLE; }

    player.update(delta)
}
render() {
    player.draw();
}
```

With this, you will notice that all I do in my render method is draw the image of the player. See how much lighter that is compared to doing logic in the render method? From this you can also see a new way of handling input. As for the player class

```
class player {
    private final int LEFT = 0;
    private final int RIGHT = 1;
    private final int IDLE = -1;
    Image img;
    int x, y;
    int direction;

    public player() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        img = new Image("myplayerimage.png");
    }

    public void draw() {
        img.draw(position.x, position.y);
    }
    public void update(int delta) {
        move();
    }
    public void move() {
        if(direction == LEFT) {
            x -= 1;
        }
        else if(direction == RIGHT) {
            x += 1;
        }
        else if(direction == IDLE) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

While this player class might not be very advanced, it at the least allows you to observe how moving increments over each frame update (each render() call is considered a frame update) can give the effect of motion. This is a linear type of motion, as in my move() method, i only increment by 1, each time the update is called. This might not seem like very much movement, but if you have a FPS of 60, you will get 60 pixels moved in one second.

In summary, to get the desired effect you want, you will need to update() your location every game tick, and draw the image at the position each update()/render() call, to present any kind of motion.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention in the player class, all slick.Images have a reference to the contextual graphics object. They don't need g.drawImage, as img.draw(x, y) works just fine, since img has it's own reference to the container's graphics object.